# Displaying the contents of an arrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, arraylist

The program below generates 10 pairs of random numbers of a certain size and stores them in an ArrayList named test -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class randomGenerate
{
    static ArrayList<String> tcase=new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<int[]> test=new ArrayList<int[]>();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        tcase.add("1");
        tcase.add("2");
        tcase.add("3");
        tcase.add("4");
        tcase.add("5");
        tcase.add("6");
        randomSelection(10,2);
        for(int i=0;i<test.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.get(i)));
        }
    }

    static int randomNo(int max,int min)
    {
        Random obj = new Random();
        int n = max - min + 1;
        int i = obj.nextInt(n);
        int randomNum =  min + i;
        return randomNum;   
    }

    static void randomSelection(int limit, int pairSize) 
    {
        int max = Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(tcase));
        int min = Integer.parseInt(Collections.min(tcase));
        System.out.println(max+"  "+min);
        int ar[]=new int[pairSize]; 
        for(int i = 0;i < limit;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < pairSize;j++)
            {
                ar[j]=randomNo(max,min);
                System.out.print(ar[j]);
            }
            test.add(ar);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that while printing the contents of the arrayList "test" only the last value is displayed. Why is it not displaying all the values.

output - (for example)

```
23
65
45
63
12
23
52
52
16
12
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: what do uyou mean last value?

Comment: From the example [1, 2] is added to the 9th position in the arrayList "test". while displaying the contents of the arrayList using a for loop only [1, 2] is displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're always modifying and adding the same array to the list at each iteration.

Think of a situation like this :

[image]

You need to create a new array at each iteration :

```
for(int i = 0;i < limit;i++){
    int ar[]=new int[pairSize]; //create a new one at each iteration
    for(int j = 0;j < pairSize;j++){
       ar[j]=randomNo(max,min);
       System.out.print(ar[j]);
    }
    test.add(ar);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the array `ar` to the `ArrayList` test each iteration in `randomSelection()`, so when you modify `ar` in the next iteration, you are modifying it inside the `ArrayList`, to solve this try:

**Way 1:**

Create a new array each iteration

```
int ar[];
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    ar =  new int[pairSize]; // Initialize inside 'for'
    for (int j = 0; j < pairSize; j++) {
        ar[j] = randomNo(max, min);
        System.out.print(ar[j]);
    }
    test.add(ar);
}
```

**Way 2:**

Create a copy of the array `ar` and add it to `test`:

```
int ar[] = new int[pairSize];
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < pairSize; j++) {
        ar[j] = randomNo(max, min);
        System.out.print(ar[j]);
    }

    test.add(ar.clone()); // Create a copy
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ZouZou. ZouZou that illustration really helped.

Comment: Thanks @Christian. You guys are like super computers